# HTML5 FileList empty in FireFox

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop, html5-audio, xfce

I'm writing this HTML5 music player that works by dragging music files onto it. (will soon use WebRTC too)

http://pepijndevos.nl/KjuMusic/

It works in Chrome, it used to work in Firefox, and still does on a friends Mac.

However, on my Xubuntu laptop, both with the default and the nightly Firefox, I get

```
FileList { length=0, item=item()}
```

when dropping one or more files. I'm not even sure anymore if this is a bug in my code, Firefox, or somewhere else in xfce.

Comment: is this still an unanswered topic? currently i've got the same problem in chrome on windows 7.

Comment: now it works for me. all i did was taking it away from being called as local file. i just opened the html document through localhost and it worked.

Comment: seems like a browsersided permission issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which file manager are you using? HTML5 Drag&Drop used to only work with Nautilus for a long time. As of this writing, PCManFM works as well, but Thunar still doesn't.

Current versions for future reference:

- Thunar 1.6.3
- PCManFM 1.1.1
- Nautilus 3.8.2

There's also a Firefox Bugzilla entry regarding this problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=609284